# Images are visible outside div

Tags: html, css, image

I want to make image slider using *transform: translate()* and div with images. My goal is slide the div with images (inside the *pics-div*) and I want **div with images not to be visible outside the *pics-div*** and images be displayed only in div where they are.

```css
#pics-div {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#left-btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 190px;
  background-color: rgb(41, 32, 170);
  transition: 0.1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#left-btn:hover {
  /* background-color: rgb(70, 13, 13); */
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px rgb(41, 32, 170);
}

#right-btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 190px;
  background-color: rgb(41, 32, 170);
  transition: 0.1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#right-btn:hover {
  /* background-color: rgb(70, 13, 13); */
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px rgb(41, 32, 170);
}
```

```html
<h3>Image slider</h3>
<div style='display: flex;'>
  <div id='left-btn'>
    <p>L</p>
  </div>
  <div id='pics-div'>
    <div style='display: flex;'>
      <img src='https://shorturl.at/chBHM' alt='Red trees' height="400" width="700">
      <img src='https://shorturl.at/aAEX5' alt='Winter house' height="400" width="700">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='right-btn'>
    <p>R</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider applying `overflow: hidden` to hide any overflow from the element's padding box:

```css
#pics-div {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#left-btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 190px;
  background-color: rgb(41, 32, 170);
  transition: 0.1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#left-btn:hover {
  /* background-color: rgb(70, 13, 13); */
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px rgb(41, 32, 170);
}

#right-btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 190px;
  background-color: rgb(41, 32, 170);
  transition: 0.1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#right-btn:hover {
  /* background-color: rgb(70, 13, 13); */
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px rgb(41, 32, 170);
}
```

```html
<h3>Image slider</h3>
<div style='display: flex;'>
  <div id='left-btn'>
    <p>L</p>
  </div>
  <div id='pics-div'>
    <div style='display: flex;'>
      <img src='https://shorturl.at/chBHM' alt='Red trees' height="400" width="700">
      <img src='https://shorturl.at/aAEX5' alt='Winter house' height="400" width="700">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='right-btn'>
    <p>R</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can [Read more about `overflow: hidden` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#hidden).

Comment: but if images will have `overflow: hidden` then when I will move them they will be still hidden

Comment: If you move the inner `<div>` of `#pics-div`, they would not be still hidden